# How do I sort on the array within a document?

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I am trying to sort on sub array data.  Here are the models involved:

Operator model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var deepPopulate = require('mongoose-deep-populate')(mongoose);
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const OperatorSchema = new Schema({
    value: {type: String, required: true},
    displaySort: {type: Number, required: true }
})
OperatorSchema.plugin(deepPopulate);
module.exports = Operator = mongoose.model('operators', OperatorSchema)
```

Operative model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var deepPopulate = require('mongoose-deep-populate')(mongoose);
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const OperativeSchema = new Schema({
    affiliation: {type: String, required: true},
    operator_REF: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'operators' },
    number: {type: Number, required: true, default: 0},
})
OperativeSchema.plugin(deepPopulate);
module.exports = Operative = mongoose.model('operatives', OperativeSchema)
```

sFilter model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var deepPopulate = require('mongoose-deep-populate')(mongoose);
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const FilterSchema = new Schema({

    affiliation: {type: String, required: true},
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    minOperative_REF: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'operatives', required: false },
    maxOperative_REF: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'operatives', required: false },
})
FilterSchema.plugin(deepPopulate);  // required for deepPopulate
module.exports = Filter = mongoose.model('sfilter', FilterSchema)
```

Here is the code that performs a GET of all sFilter documents:

```
Filter.find()
.deepPopulate(filter_deepPopulateString)
.then(fil => {
    if(fil.length > 0 ) {
        res.json(fil);
    } else {
        res.status(401).json({error: 'No filter found'});
    }
});
```

Here is the filter_deepPopulateString :

```
'minOperative_REF.operator_REF maxOperative_REF.operator_REF'
```

Here is the 'get' result:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5d55907094315b13143b7623",
        "affiliation": "cvimmkfzukyn2qdrxumz",
        "name": "25 - 29",
        "__v": 0,
        "minOperative_REF": {
            "number": 25,
            "_id": "5d55916894315b13143b7628",
            "affiliation": "cvimmkfzukyn2qdrxumz",
            "operator_REF": {
                "_id": "5d531df7dc2c19253c3ebca2",
                "value": ">=",
                "displaySort": -20,
                "__v": 0
            },
            "__v": 0
        },
        "maxOperative_REF": {
            "number": 29,
            "_id": "5d55917194315b13143b7629",
            "affiliation": "cvimmkfzukyn2qdrxumz",
            "operator_REF": {
                "_id": "5d531df8dc2c19253c3ebca3",
                "value": "<=",
                "displaySort": 20,
                "__v": 0
            },
            "__v": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "5d55a9b86ad2d22f1cf7983c",
        "affiliation": "cvimmkfzukyn2qdrxumz",
        "name": "1 - 19",
        "__v": 0,
        "minOperative_REF": {
            "number": 1,
            "_id": "5d55913c94315b13143b7624",
            "affiliation": "cvimmkfzukyn2qdrxumz",
            "operator_REF": {
                "_id": "5d531df7dc2c19253c3ebca2",
                "value": ">=",
                "displaySort": -20,
                "__v": 0
            },
            "__v": 0
        },
        "maxOperative_REF": {
            "number": 19,
            "_id": "5d55914b94315b13143b7625",
            "affiliation": "cvimmkfzukyn2qdrxumz",
            "operator_REF": {
                "_id": "5d531df8dc2c19253c3ebca3",
                "value": "<=",
                "displaySort": 20,
                "__v": 0
            },
            "__v": 0
        }
    }
]
```

I would like to sort by the following data:

```
"minOperative_REF": { "number": 25
"minOperative_REF": { "number": 1
```

This is what I want the results to be:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5d55a9b86ad2d22f1cf7983c",
        "affiliation": "cvimmkfzukyn2qdrxumz",
        "name": "1 - 19",
        "__v": 0,
        "minOperative_REF": {
            "number": 1,
            "_id": "5d55913c94315b13143b7624",
            "affiliation": "cvimmkfzukyn2qdrxumz",
            "operator_REF": {
                "_id": "5d531df7dc2c19253c3ebca2",
                "value": ">=",
                "displaySort": -20,
                "__v": 0
            },
            "__v": 0
        },
        "maxOperative_REF": {
            "number": 19,
            "_id": "5d55914b94315b13143b7625",
            "affiliation": "cvimmkfzukyn2qdrxumz",
            "operator_REF": {
                "_id": "5d531df8dc2c19253c3ebca3",
                "value": "<=",
                "displaySort": 20,
                "__v": 0
            },
            "__v": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "5d55907094315b13143b7623",
        "affiliation": "cvimmkfzukyn2qdrxumz",
        "name": "25 - 29",
        "__v": 0,
        "minOperative_REF": {
            "number": 25,
            "_id": "5d55916894315b13143b7628",
            "affiliation": "cvimmkfzukyn2qdrxumz",
            "operator_REF": {
                "_id": "5d531df7dc2c19253c3ebca2",
                "value": ">=",
                "displaySort": -20,
                "__v": 0
            },
            "__v": 0
        },
        "maxOperative_REF": {
            "number": 29,
            "_id": "5d55917194315b13143b7629",
            "affiliation": "cvimmkfzukyn2qdrxumz",
            "operator_REF": {
                "_id": "5d531df8dc2c19253c3ebca3",
                "value": "<=",
                "displaySort": 20,
                "__v": 0
            },
            "__v": 0
        }
    }
]
```

Here is the deepPopulate plugin that I am using : https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-deep-populate

Comment: If your document is returned from .findOne() function then why is that in an array ?If it's not the issue please check my answer, Also you can use .findById() if you would like to !!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know mongoDB does sort on documents, but does not sort objects in an array inside response document (To be clear - DB can use field from nested object of an array to sort returned documents), Since you're using `.findOne()` you'll only be returning one document in the response there is no value to your sort stage. In case if you've multiple documents returned something like when using `.find()` then DB would definitely sort documents based on nested object's field, still it compares with other documents but not with other objects in same array of same document returned.

In case if you still need it try doing it your code or by using `$aggregate` to fetch the document and then use `$unwind` on that array then you can sort those objects and again push back to the same array on `$group` stage, that possible way you can still return one document with sorted array. I'm not sure how `deepPopulate` work, if it's something similar to `.populate` in mongoose then you can use `$lookup` (just a hint though).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7237613/srinivasy : I am fairly new to mongoDB and don't understand where $aggregate should be used?  should it be used as a dot operator after my find? (like I am trying with .sort ) Can you provide an example?

Comment: @MLissCetrus : what language are you using for your back-end application ?

Comment: Js as a back-end ?? Ok anyhow I can provide few links where you can check how to use aggregate, Basically it is similar to .find(), it is a more powerful replacement to .find(), you'll use it on your collection same-way you use it find(). Please check this : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/index.html , Or if you still help, I can write the working query for you if you can provide me with entire document rather than that array !! that would be easy to understand on both ends..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7237613/srinivasy - thank you very much for the offer, let me simplify the model so I can understand it and it's easier for you to work with.

Comment: @MLissCetrus : Yes please give me a document from collections, that would be easy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7237613/srinivasy - check out question, let me know if that helps

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7237613/srinivasy - is the question any better now ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198064/discussion-between-srinivasy-and-mlisscetrus).